# Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous given $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=a$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=b$

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital, uniform-continuity

> Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be continuous. Assume
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &f(x) \rightarrow a \quad \text { for } x \rightarrow-\infty\\
> &f(x) \rightarrow b \quad \text { for } x \rightarrow \infty
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I'm lost here.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

For "very small" $x_1, x_2$, you have $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|f(x_1)-a+a-f(x_2)|\leq |f(x_1)-a|+|f(x_2)-a|$.

For "very large" $x_1, x_2$, you have $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|f(x_1)-b+b-f(x_2)|\leq |f(x_1)-b|+|f(x_2)-b|$.

For everything in between, functions, continuous on closed intervals, are uniformly continuous.

Comment: My problem is that $f$ is defined on the entire $\mathbb R$. If this was not the case I could just use the following theorem  "Every continuous function $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous"

Comment: @Xenusi Sure, that's why I wrote **three** hints. Which, judging by your reply, you didn't even take the time to read and consider...

Comment: I have read them. I have also shown that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| < \epsilon$

Comment: I can't see have to use what I have shown to say that $f$ is uni. cont.